# How to initialie an ArrayList to have 0 entries (Java)?

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I declare an ArrayList like so:

```
private ArrayList<String> list;
```

On a separate line, I would like to declare a list with 0 entries. How do I do this?

Edit: I want to write a constructor method for a class. Outside the method, at the class level, I have declared  `private ArrayList<String> list;` I would like to initialize list to have 0 entries inside the constructor.

Comment: There wont be ArrayList object, till you create it. Even after creating there wont be any elements unless you add it. Hence there will be 0 entries.

Comment: What do you mean? When you create the list, it will be empty.

Comment: An ArrayList has no entries just after being created with an empty constructor. What do you mean EXACTLY?

Comment: Ok. I have a problem in front of me where I am supposed to write the various methods for a class. The variables to be used in the methods are declared at the class level (outside the methods). One of these declarations is: private ArrayList <String> list; I am not sure whether this means an empty ArrayList of Strings has been created. I am also not sure why the declaration is not written instead as: ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); In the constructor method I am supposed to "initialize list to have zero entries".

Answer (score 2):

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Just say you have class named MyClass, use the constructor as:

```
public class MyClass {
  private ArrayList<String> list;
  MyClass() {
  list = new ArrayList<>();//ArrayList with 0 size or empty ArrayList, basically.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance of the list

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can provide an intial start capacity

> ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
>   Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(10); //start capacity of 10 elements
```

It's best to fill in start capacity if you know the approximate amount of elements to reduce lots of resizes